# PHP execution timing out after update

Tags: apache-2.2, php, timeout

Originally posted on stackoverflow, but I think it'd be more appropriate here.

Needed Finfo but deleted msi package, so uninstalled php 5.3.0, downloaded 5.3.2 and installed. Now all my sites have spurious errors and execution time outs. Originally updated with VC9 build but then realised error and updated with VC6 (with same problem).

Example error:

Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in ...Core.php on line 60

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your connection definition?

If you can successfully connect after that, open up **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** in Notepad and add the following line. After you do this, you should be able to connect with `localhost`.

`::1              localhost`

I am making assumptions that your Operating System is either Windows Vista or Windows 7 and you have IPv6 enabled, as these combinations can cause problems like this.

Comment: I've since gone back to 5.3.0 so can't verify this, but it seems a plausable remedy.